# Edit Document in Sharepoint

Tags: excel

I have an issue when editing and save sharepoint Office document.

Firstly if I am right clicking on the document and saving it. It is fast and fine.

If I try to edit it in office, it opens very slow (40 secs for 600KB).

So a blank document will come out, then there comes a prompt saying contacting server. And have to wait for along time for it to really show me the document. So I want to know what is the purpose of contacting server after downloading the document. Or what really happens underneath when I choose to edit a document in office rather than right clicking and saving it onto my desktop.

---

Update:

I have an image of wireshark logs here at 
[image: wireshark]

10.152 is Server

10.143 is Client

This is using wireshark to view the logs. A lot of my machine is experiencing slowness in the editing document from sharepoint.

This is the logs on one of my client. How I interpret the logs is that everytime the file is download finish (Frame 763). It will send a ack at frame 764. But it seems the receiving end dun received it in time and try to issue a DUP ACK to the client. When this happens it take 9 second (21 - 12) to allow the client to send packet again. Why is this so?

Feel free to correct me if I interpret it wrongly. I am not very experience in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

never meet this strange problem

when you choose to edit a document directly, the Word client will send some additional request to sharepoint,

e.g. 
 /_vti_bin/lists.asmx, /_vti_bin/webs.asmx,/_vti_bin/workflow.asmx. /_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll, /_vti_bin/shtml/vti_rpc and many others.

so there are tow things you can do:

1. test on other clients
2. use Fiddler to find out which request(s)  behave so badly